# In Excel, is it possible to inherit the formula instead of the value when referencing a cell

Tags: excel, inheritance, excel-formula

Is it in Excel possible to inherit the formula instead of the value when referencing a cell?

Excel has many powerful features but as far I know this one is not one of them, although in my noble opinion it is an elementary one.

In my own usage scenario, the column formula is based on a template that on is own is also based on an other template, and so on. The results is a quit complex (extended) inheritance tree where the formula somewhere on the line can be changed (overwritten), once or multiple times.

Of course it is also essential that the mechanism of relative and absolute referencing is respected.

Example:

```
A1: =$B1+$C1
A2: =InheritFrom($A$1) --> what will result in =$B2+$C2
A3: =InheritFrom($A$2) --> what will result in =$B3+$C3
A4: =($B4+$C4)*2
A5: =InheritFrom($A$4) --> what will result in =($B5+$C5)*2
A6: =($D6*Z6)/12+$B6
A7: =InheritFrom($A$6) --> what will result in =($D7*Z7)/12+$B7
A8: =InheritFrom($A$1) --> what will result in =$B8+$C8
A9: =InheritFrom($A$7) --> what will result in =($D9*Z9)/12+$B9
A10:=100
A11:=InheritFrom($A$10) --> what will result in =100
```

This is very simplified example. The real case scenario is much more complex, but the basic principles are the same.

An other possible advantage would be: It could make maintaining large sheets (tables) much easier. When the formula of column is changed you don't have to update the same formula for each row.

Comment: It's not clear from your excample why you don't just fill down the formulas?  That seems easier than building the functionality you describe.

Comment: You can switch to R1C1 reference style and update quicker. See post here:http://http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/the-beauty-of-the-r1c1-reference-style/

Comment: As mentioned by @TimWilliams above, all you need is the correct formula and `Ctrl+D`. Put `=($B1+$C1)*(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/3)+1)` in A1 then select A1:A5 and tap `Ctrl+D` (aka *Fill Down*) or with just A1 selected double-click the tiny *fill handle* square in the lower right corner.

Comment: Thanks. The easy update was given as an example of an advantage of this feature. I can think of many more. The real reason I'm looking for this feature is for complex inheritance scenario's. When the formula is updated somewhere in the hierarchy it is impossible to update all cells manually. The formula can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

By storing formulas in *Defined Names* you can achieve what you want.  For a really good example of using this technique, see:

[Loan Template from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/results.aspx?qu=loan&CTT=1#ai:TC102810052%7C)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I know what "Defined Names" are but I can't see how they could be solution? I'm sorry. I checked some of the loan templates. I don't see anything special about the way 'Names' are used, other then an other way of referencing a cell.